# How does one get ordinate values that are incremental?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, deque

I have a separate scrape thread function that appends values to a deque register. The following function reads the deque values and plots them to screen.

```
def display_plt():
    for i in range((5000)) : 
        plt.grid()
        plt.scatter(my_time, bid_price)
        plt.pause(0.5)
        plt.show()
        #plt.clf() 
        plt.cla()
        if i % 40 == 0:
            print(bid_price)
t1 = Thread(target=scrape)
t1.start()
display_plt()
```

When I show the plot, the ordinate coordinated do not increase at a consistant amount.
See picture. Note the top three numbers on the left. The ordinate values are from a 200 element rolling deque register. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: When you use multiple threads, there's no reason to expect a consistent number of iterations in the other thread.

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The [mre] should include **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include a mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted. The code, and or data should be sufficient to run.

Comment: I did not state that the data was inconsistent. Look at the graph. What type of data could possibly change the tick values on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My data was in string format. Matplotlib was not converting it properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).